# How to fetch array of records with like query in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have to fetch category items which is in connected category. for example '70' has connected category like this '710,153,410' in database table.
when I click 70 means also want to fetch the items which is in 710,153, and 410.
But I get now only 410. How to fetch these all ?

```
    //get connected category
    $connected_cat_results = getCategory(array('id'=>'70'))->row();
    $connected_categories = explode(',',$connected_cat_results->connected_category);
    foreach($connected_categories as $cat)
    {
        $condition['advertisements.category LIKE'] = '%'.$cat.',';
    }
```

Comment: you should try where in...no need to iterate using foreach
$car = array('AA', BB', 'CC');)
EX: $this->db->where_in('car_name', $car);

Comment: How can use Like query in this ?